# Instagram API Javascript not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, api, instagram, middleman

I have created a simple landing page for my upcoming site. I am pretty inexperienced with JavaScript and this fix could be simple.

I am using Instagram's API to get data from my Instagram account. I am displaying various account statistics such as the total number of likes and total number of comments made to my account. I have approached this by looping through each post and getting the like and comment count, and simply adding it together.

I am using Middleman, the static site generator to create the site. I have used it before and am somewhat happy with it as I am also learning Ruby.

The stats show up correctly on desktop, but on mobile (tested on Apple iPhone 5S), it doesn't seem to loop through the media, I think it is just getting the like count from the latest post? I would really appreciate the help with this!

Everything else apart from the stats are working fine (Displaying profile picture, feed, etc).

The site is www.gymspotter.info

(please scale down the browser window as you will get the message "Sorry, the site is not currently optimised for your screen size.") - It's mobile only at the moment.

Thanks again,
I hope I have included everything necessary

Comment: To receive help, you have to reproduce a minimal demo of your issue on http://jsbin.com/ .